# 3d element not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, transform

I'm trying to rotate 2 divs like this http://jsfiddle.net/4mFLL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
.psd {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    perspective: 700px;
    -webkit-perspective: 700px;
    -moz-transform: perspective(700px);
}

.foo {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #F00;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: rotateX(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-origin: top;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-20deg);
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position: fixed;">
            <div class="psd">
                <div class="foo">
                    <p>Text 1</p>
                    <div class="foo">
                        <p>Text 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is working in Chrome but not in Firefox. Does firefox not support these kinds of rotations or did I miss a css property?

Busti

Comment: usually errors like this are syntax errors due to the fact that some of the properties you are using are experimental. The best place to start is to verify that the syntax is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change .foo style to:

```
.foo {
    display: block;
    }
```